# Do I need to set up static routes between routers for bi-directional device access?

Tags: router, wifi, bridge, ip-routing

I've got two TP-link routers where one (Remote router 192.168.2.4) is making a WDS bridge connection to another (Main router 192.168.2.2) on a static 2.4 ghz wifi channel.  Main router is also doing DHCP and WAN port has internet access (PPPoe).  Devices connected to Remote router are set up with static IP (also on 192.168.2.x) and static gateway (192.168.2.2) and have working internet connectivity and can "see" (or at least ping) devices connected to Main router.

Devices connected directly to Main router can ping Remote router (192.168.2.4) but can't ping any devices connected to Remote router, and that's the problem.  NAT is disabled on the Remote router (because I think it has to be for the WDS bridge to work) so I don't know if that's an issue.

I've never set up routing-table entries before on any router, and I'm wondering if that's what I need to have so that Main devices can see Remote devices.  If so, on what router (Main or Remote) do I set up the routing tables on?

Network mask on everything is 255.255.255.0

If I set the IP/Gateway of Remote PC to automatic, then Remote PC gets IP/Gateway from DHCP server (which is Main router) and this does work. This doesn't change anything - Remote PC has internet access and can ping Local PC. Local PC still can't ping Remote PC.

I've also enabled NAT on Remote router, and still have bridge functionality, but again this doesn't change anything (Local PC still can't ping Remote PC).

Comment: What is the network mask used on all your devices?

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention it but I guess that all clients have the same network mask 255.255.255.0 correct?

Since the 2 routers are bridged and all clients on both routers use the same network - 192.168.2.0/24 - there is no need for routing entries.

There are 2 possible causes I can think of:

Either a firewall issue that disallows traffic from the wireless bridge interface of the Main router to its Ethernet ports.

Or you have to do some kind of bridging between the Wlan interface and 
the Ethernet interface of your Remote router.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was sort of dumb, but the Remote PC (being windoze 7) wasn't set up to respond to pings.  I've fixed that.  So now, if Local PC is temporarily connected (ethernet cable) to Lan port A on Remote router, and Remote PC is connected (ethernet cable) to Lan port B on Remote router, both PC's can ping each other.  If Local PC is connected back to Main router (ethernet cable to Lan port) then Remote PC can still ping Local PC, Local PC *can not* ping Remote PC.  Local PC, when connected to Main router *can* ping other devices also connected to Main router.

Comment: Ok, for some reason it's working now.  All devices can see/ping each other, and all devices have internet access.

Comment: Nice that you got it working! (was close with my suggestion on firewall issues - just wrong device!) :)

Comment: Just a quick note, if you change Remote PC from one router to the other, there is the chance you will lose connectivity until internal ARP tables expire. That may be reason it did not work at first, and then it solved itself.